# CoffeeScript not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to get a link_to tag when clicked to execute coffee script code. I can't get this to work, when I click the 'ADD' link the page refreshes and I can see ?id=add-link

This is what I have:

```
#add.coffee
$(document).on "page:change", ->
 $('#add-link').click ->
  alert "clicked"
```

link_to tag in the view template:

```
<%= link_to "ADD", id: "add-link" %>
```

application.js

```
//= require_tree .
//= require add
```

gemfile:

```
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1'
```

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

Your coffeescript is fine. You messed up your `link_to`. Its second parameter is the url. Customization (id, class, etc.) comes *after*.

```
<%= link_to "ADD", nil, id: "add-link" %>
```

Actually, don't use `link_to` at all here.

```
<a id='add-link' href='#'>ADD</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that and the alert message didn't execute.

Comment: Well, combine this with the other suggestion and add your listener on `page:load` too.

Comment: Is this what you mean? 

    $(document).on 'page:load', ->

    $(document).on 'page:change', ->

      $('#add-link').click ->

        alert "clicked"

Comment: @rubyist: hm, looking at turbolinks docs, it appears that `page:change` _should_ be fired on initial page load. Something else is wrong there.